# Python: How to rewrite function to be used with arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have simple function which looks like that:

```
def summer_scalar(x):
    a = np.array([1,2,3])
    b = np.array([7,8,9])
    return sum(a - b * x)
```

It works, but problems appear if I want to use it with arrays, for example Numpy arrays. If I submit numpy array I get error:

```
summer_scalar(np.array([7,8,9,7]))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

I guess the reason is that it treats all my arrays as peers, but they are not: elements from arguments should be processed one after one and form an output array, arguments from a and b should be processed as they were before. So it tries to sum arrays of different size and fails.

What can I do?

I can rewrite my method:

```
def summer(x):
    a = np.array([1,2,3])
    b = np.array([7,8,9])
    s = 0
    for ai,bi in zip(a,b):
        s = s + ai - bi* x 
        #print ai,bi,s
    return s
```

This works.

A question is: is there a better way to modify my method for vector operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are better ways.

**Method #1**

Direct translation of the stated problem to a vectorized mindset leads us to leverage [`NumPy broacasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
(a-b*x[:,None]).sum(1)
```

That's an outer product, so we can also use NumPy ufunc to do the same -

```
(a-np.multiply.outer(x,b)).sum(1)
```

---

**Method #2**

Looking closely, it seems we won't need that explicit `dimension-extension+broadcasting` and we could just sum the elements in `a` and `b` and do something like this -

```
a.sum(0) - x*b.sum(0)
```

We could employ [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) here to replace `x*b.sum(0)`, like so -

```
a.sum(0) - np.einsum('i,j->i', x,b)
```

Again, `a.sum(0)` could be replaced by one more `einsum` -

```
np.einsum('i->',a) - np.einsum('i,j->i', x,b)
```

So, lots of options to vectorize such an operation!